# How to put axes with PSTricks?. I use \psaxes... but I have no results

Tags: pstricks

I want to use `\psaxes` and `\psgrid` but it doesn't runs well.

What am I doing wring?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(12,6) %\malla
% \psaxes{<->}(3,3)
% \psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt,labels=none,ticks=none]{<->}(2,1)(0,0)(4,3)
 \rput(1,2){\circlenode{V}{\textcolor{blue}{Vigo}}}
 \rput(1,5){\circlenode{C}{\textcolor{magenta}{Coru\~na}}}
 \rput(3,2){\circlenode{S}{\textcolor{red}{Scq}}}
 \rput(3,5){\circlenode{P}{\textcolor{green}{Po}}}

 \ncarc[arcangle=33]{->}{V}{C}
 \naput*{\small 45 \euro}   % This line show error on compiling.

 \ncarc[arcangle=11]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small 25 \euro }

 \ncarc[arcangle=75]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small{\blue 15 \euro} }

 \psbezier[linecolor=blue, linestyle=dashed]{*-*}(4,-0.5)(6,6)(8,-2)(10,2)

\rput(8,3){Esto é unha proba.}

\pscurve[linecolor=blue, linewidth=0.035]{o-o}(6,5)(7,4)(8,5.8)(9,5.8)(10,4)(11,6)

\psdots[dotsize=0.4](10,2)

\pscustom{
\pscurve(10,-2)(11,2)(11.5,1)
\psline(11.5,1)(11.5,-1)
\fill[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me, just after posting...i realized.

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

Solution: You must include the line `\usepackage{pst-plot}`.